# PECL stats_rand_gen_normal always returns the same value

Tags: php, statistics, pecl

With PHP 7.3, I'm trying to use the PECL stats extension: https://pecl.php.net/package/stats

Especially, I'm interested in generating random values following a normal distribution, with the function [stats_rand_gen_normal](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.stats-rand-gen-normal.php)

In my script, the function always returns the same result. 
I tried in CLI, to be sure :

```
php -r "echo(stats_rand_gen_normal(0,1));"
```

Every execution prints the same number.

So it's a random value which is always the same... What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to me like a bug too and I have make a [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78233).
There is a solution on stackoverflow using a [custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951563/how-can-i-choose-a-random-number-but-with-a-normal-probability-distribution-in-p#answer-15952104).

Answer (score 1):

You should use [stats_rand_setall()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stats-rand-setall.php) to seed values to the random generator.